# Unable to resolve NULL driver Lumen 5.6

Tags: email, config, lumen

In a development environment all works fine.
But in production, Lumen returns me `Unable to resolve NULL driver [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager]`

After some research, I discovered that when I debug $app:

In both mode, all configurations is loaded.

```
["loadedConfigurations":protected]=>
    array(5) {
    ["mail"]=> bool(true)
    //other keys ...
  }
```

But:

*In development, the debug returns all my Lumen's configuration:*

```
array(6) {
    ["app"]=>
    *RECURSION*
    ["Laravel\Lumen\Application"]=>
    *RECURSION*
    ["path"]=>
    string(17) "/var/www/html/app"
    ["config"]=>
    object(Illuminate\Config\Repository)#5 (1) {
      ["items":protected]=>
      array(5) {
      //all keys ...
     }
```

*On production (share hosting server), the debug doesn't return configuration's keys :*

```
 array(6) {
    ["app"]=>
    *RECURSION*
    ["Laravel\Lumen\Application"]=>
    *RECURSION*
    ["path"]=>
    string(11) "/htdocs/app"
    ["config"]=>
    object(Illuminate\Config\Repository)#5 (1) {
      ["items":protected]=>
      array(0) {
          //no keys
      }
    }
```

This is the reason for which Lumen doesn't find driver for the mailing.
Now I can't explain why Lumen ignores my configuration. Someone knows?

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

I just found the reason of this problem.
In production, the server is case sensitive.
My directory was `/Config` and it need `/config` in lower case